# How to show preselected boolean value with Primeng InputSwitch in form control?

Tags: javascript, angular, toggle, primeng

I am struggling with `p-inputSwitch` in angular.

I have an **edit** button in another component. Once I click it, a `p-dialog` pops up and it has the `form` below.

When the dialog is displayed, I want to make the preselected status on `p-inputSwitch` stay. It is inside the form control. Here is the code I made:

**<home.component.html>**

```js
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (submit)="onSubmitForm()">
  <div>
    <p-inputSwitch
      formControlName="ShowMe"
      (onChange) = "test($event)"    
    ></p-inputSwitch>
  </div>
</form>
```

**<home.component.ts>**

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  checked: boolean;

  myForm = this.fb.group({
    ShowMe: [null, Validators.required],
  });

  constructor(
    private fb: UntypedFormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.test();
  }

  test(e: any) {
    this.checked = e.checked;
    console.log(this.checked);
  }
}
```

On the server side, I can see the `ShowMe` value is stored as either 0 or 1.

- If it is `0`, the `checked` should be `false` and the `p-inputSwitch`
  should be `off`.
- If it is `1`, the `checked` should be `true` and the
  `p-inputSwitch` should be `on`.

How can I see the preselected status on the input switch? Please help me out with any example code.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code, there was a few bugs. Following this code, I did not have p-inputSwitch for my local, but I made a checkbox example over there which is the same logic:

TS ->

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { UntypedFormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private fb: UntypedFormBuilder) {}

  checked: boolean = true;

  myForm = this.fb.group({
    ShowMe: [false, Validators.required],
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm.patchValue({ ShowMe: false });
  }

  test(e?: any) {
    this.checked = e.checked;
    console.log(this.checked);
  }

  onSubmitForm() {
    
  }
}
```

HTML ->

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (submit)="onSubmitForm()">
  <div>
    <input
      #checkbox
      type="checkbox"
      formControlName="ShowMe"
      (change)="test(checkbox)"
    />
  </div>
</form>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-61najh?file=src/app/app.component.html

Good luck.

Comment: thanks but this is not what I want.. I should have mentioned more details on the issue. Let me edit my initial question.